# SQL Server 2008 select column from comma separated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table 1:

```
Id | Name
1  | Example1
2  | Example2
```

Table 2:

```
Id  | Table1_IDs
1   | 1,2
2   | 2
```

I want to select table1 from table2 using `table1_IDs` like:

```
select * 
from table1
where id in (select t.table1_IDs from table2 t)
```

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble... (One value per row is the SQL way!)

Comment: In this case, you need to restructure you tables like this: table1(Id, Name),  with ID the primary key. Table2(id, id_ref) with a compound primary key (id, id_ref). May I ask what you try to achieve ?

Comment: Any other options with same structure? like with sub query or functions etc...

Comment: It's probably possible to do, but not with good performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can build query string end then use `sp_executesql` stored procedure to run it. Something like this (not tested)

```
declare @ids varchar(2000)
select @ids = coalesce(@ids + ',', '') +  convert(varchar(100), table1_IDs)
from table2

declare @query nvarchar(2000) = 'select * from table1 where id in (' + @ids + ')'
execute sp_executesql @query
```

But this is not good idea to use coma separated values becaouse it decrease perfomance. Try to refactor yours tables.

Answer (score 0):

> Any other options with same structure?

```
select * from table1 ta join
    (
    SELECT id,  
         LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Certs
          from  (

    SELECT id,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(value,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
    FROM   table2

)  t 
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)) b on b.id=ta.id
```

break table2 comma delemeted into rows and use with Table1 in Join.